# Why does a theorem in G.H. Hardy's Introduction to the Theory of Numbers looks like it implies that 1 is prime?

Tags: arithmetic

In G.H. Hardy's 6th edition of *Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*, there is a theorem that **looks** like it implies that $1$ is prime:

"Theorem 1. Every positive integer, except $1$, is a product of primes. (p. 2)"

$17$ is a positive integer, but the factors of $17$ are not both prime.

Is this because of how Euclid defines a prime number in Book VII of *Euclid's Elements*? The translation I have says:

"A prime number is that which is measured by an unit alone".

If I were to take a couple of guesses, either I ignore $1$ as a factor or
I bought a bad copy of G.H. Hardy's *Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*.

**Edit**: Not the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, it is just Theorem 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hardy never said *more than one* prime - $17$ is the product of the single number "$17$," which is prime.

Comment: And, indeed, 1 is also a product of primes, the number of primes in the product being zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson But Hardy didn't say "iff"! :)

Comment: But Hardy apparently wrote, Every positive integer **except 1** is a product of primes (emphasis added). To me, that says he didn't recognize empty products as products.

Comment: Wow I didn't know a product could be a single value. 

So a product results from multiplying at least one number?

Comment: @ChazBiroan Actually, as Gerry Myerson observed you can even take the product of the emptyset! See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product).

Comment: Super glad I asked. I was being driven mad that I might have bought a badly printed copy. Thanks all!